# Flutter: How to Solve Stuck in Running Pod Install Error?

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, visual-studio-code, cocoapods

I am developing a flutter project with VSCode. Today, I download my flutter project folder to Mac. I stuck in running pod install.

I deleted the pod file and run this code

```
Pod install
```

and I got this error.

No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

I also tried to set from Xcode runner target level to 8. However, it should be at least 11.

What can I do?

Thanks for helping.
(M2 Silicon Valley)

Here is my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: you have to run `pod install` command inside ios folder.

Comment: @NazırDogan I run pod install inside iOS folder.

Comment: it's interesting. you may try `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` also did you try to create a blank flutter project without an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Merhaba, I recommend following the next steps;

1- Clear XCode's "Derived Data" from; `/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

2- Open the project again and remove the podfiles inside your ios folder.

3- Open project terminal and run; `flutter clean && flutter pub get`

4- Get inside the newly generated podfile and make your desired changes like min. platfrom etc..

5- Open project terminal again and run;

-`cd ios`

-`sudo gem install cocoapods`

-`pod install`

Now you can try again to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --user-install
```